# Why does this scala tail recursive function throws java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, tail-recursion, stack-overflow

The below simple function is tail recursive. However, it still throws `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. Could anyone please help me understand why I get this?

I have tried tail recursive functions with lists that contain millions items, but never get `StackOverflowError`. Or isn't this function tail recursive?

```
def recursion(i: Int): Int = {
  if (i == 20000) i
  else {
    recursion(i + 1)
  }
}

recursion(0)
```

Update: Adding `@tailrec` does solve the problem, even if I increase the limit to 2147483647. Thanks @tiran for your answer

Comment: You can check for the tail recursion by adding `@tailrec` annotation to the function. This is tail recursive and doesn't throw SOE for me.

Comment: This is tail recursive alright - but do you perhaps have another function named `recursion` in your REPL session/elsewhere that overrides this function?

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I created a test app with only one function and it called recursion.

Adding @tailrec to the function does solve this problem. Thanks tiran

Comment: actually addition of `@tailrec` shouldn't solve the problem because it's only an annotation that tells compiler `I think this function is tailrecursive, but check it and tell me if it's differently`.

Comment: This is confusing. Before I added `@tailrec`, I always get SOF, but now I don't have it anymore, even when I remove the `@tailrec` or change the function name without the annotation. I'm using intelliJ 13 (community edition).

Comment: @SamVo to rephrase goral -- it does not tells compiler to perform TCO (Tail call optimization), which will be done with and without annotation, instead it tells to fail compilation in case it's not possible to perform.

Comment: @SamVo what is the enclosing context of that method? An object? A class? a function that is tail recursive might be or not be optimized depending on if it can be overridden.

Comment: "but now I don't have it anymore" --> The intellij compiler (in v13) does not see all changes. Perhaps your code was not properly recompiled. When in doubt, do a rebuild or use the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The function is tail-recursive and in fact the compiler optimizes it as expected. Your example works just fine in my scala 2.11.2 REPL (I added a couple of zeros, just to prove the point better)

```
scala> def recursion(i: Int): Int = {
     |   if (i == 2000000) i
     |   else {
     |     recursion(i + 1)
     | }
     | }
recursion: (i: Int)Int

scala> recursion(0)
res0: Int = 2000000
```

About `@tailrec`, it can't "solve" anything. `@tailrec` is an annotation that triggers a compile-time error in case tail-call optimization (TCO) cannot be performed on the annotated function.

So, TCO is always performed whenever possible, regardless of the `@tailrec` annotation.

Since your problem went away just recompiling, your IDE was probably in some dirty state and the edit simply triggered a clean compilation. The code was fine from the very begin.

Answer (score 1):

In every language, with local differences, every time you invoke a function call, you create a new allocation on a memory zone called "stack" to store information about the function, such as parameters and return address. When the function returns you deallocate the corresponding stack block and return to the caller.

Suppose you have a function like:

```
def f(i:Integer) = {
  if (i <= 0) 0
 else f(i-1)
}
```

if you call f(3), you get:

f(3) -> calls -> f(2) -> calls -> f(1) -> calls -> f(0)

and your stack, when is at its maximum height, looks like:

```
stack(f(0))
stack(f(1))
stack(f(2))
stack(f(3))
```

Once the f(0) call returns, its block gets deallocated and so does, in sequence, the ones from f(1), f(2), f(3), and your stack deflates.

There is a limit to the maximum height that the stack of a program can have at any time. your function recurses 20000 times, which is more than such limit, so the JVM gets angry and throws that exception.

Adding @tailrec tells the computer to compile your function as tail recursive, i.e. to (more or less) transform it in a while loop that does not allocate stack space such as:

```
def recursion(i:Int) = {
  while(i<20000) {
    i++
  }
  i
}
```

Therefore you don't break the stack ceiling :)

EDIT: As pointed out by others, @tailrec doesn't tell the compiler to perform TCO, but asks the compiler to fail if TCO can't be performed on the method, thereby guaranteeing TCO on the method in case of compiling success.

Comment: Actually, incorrect. `@tailrec` only tells the compiler to fail compilation if it can't perform tail-call optimization on the annotated method, but it doesn't trigger it.